# Extending base mobile azure sample (.net backend)

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, azure, service

So, i create a azure mobile service, downloaded a project and run it.
After the first launch, i see some new tables in DB: `TodoItems` (with 2 items) and `_MigrationHistory`. So far so good.

Now, i'd like to add an extra table.

1. I'm making new model `MyModel:EntityData { public string MyData { get; set; }`
2. Making a new controller `MyModelController:TableController<MyModel>` which is a copy of TodoItemController, where `TodoItem` is replaced with `MyModel`
3. Added `public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }` to MyProjectContext.cs
4. Adding to the WebApiConfig a line `context.Set<MyModel>().Add(new MyModel{MyData= "test"});`

Do i forget something?

After deleting all tables and re-publishing and running my mobile application, i'm getting **MobileServiceInvalidOperationException** exception and my tables are empty (even `TodoItems` is empty).

**EDIT**: i'm not sure where is the core of the problem. If to add to the mobile app a line

```
private IMobileServiceTable<MyModel> myItemsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<MyModel>();
```

It would throw InvalidOperationException. But `MyModels` table exists in a db, i can see it via db manager...

**EDIT2**:

- Okay, i removed all additional code (with MyModels) and removed all tables in db. Re-publish mobile service, run app and again i see 2 tables: `TodoItems` (with 2 items) and `_MigrationHistory`.
- Now, i added line `public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }` to MyProjectContext.cs, removed all tables in db, run app and now i see 3 tables: `MyModels`, `TodoItems` (with 2 items) and `_MigrationHistory`.
- When i added line `context.Set<MyModel>().Add(new MyModel{MyData= "test"});` - after this moment seeding went wrong: i see 3 tables `MyModels`, `TodoItems` and `_MigrationHistory`, but `TodoItems` is empty now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in line `context.Set<MyModel>().Add(new MyModel{MyData= "test"});`. I forgot to initialize `Id`: thought it would be autoincremented.

Fixed line is `context.Set<MyModel>().Add(new MyModel{MyData= "test", Id = "666"});`

EDIT1: just another problem i faced: if there's exception in app's line `var myTable = MobileService.GetTable<MyModel>();`, be sure you added `Id` field to your model.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more tricky than it should be but the reason for the error is that the initializer doesn't see that the MyModel table isn't there -- only that the TodoItem model hasn't changed.

The easiest workaround is that you just add to your MyModel DbSet to existing todoitem context instead of adding a new MyModelContext so that it looks like this:

```
    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
```

Then you can also just have one DB initializer, for example looking like this:

```
    protected override void Seed(henrikntest13Context context)
    {
        List<TodoItem> todoItems = new List<TodoItem>
        {
            new TodoItem { Id = "1", Text = "First item", Complete = false },
            new TodoItem { Id = "2", Text = "Second item", Complete = false },
        };

        foreach (TodoItem todoItem in todoItems)
        {
            context.Set<TodoItem>().Add(todoItem);
        }

        List<MyModel> myModels = new List<MyModel>
        {
            new MyModel { Id = "1", MyData = "First Item"},
            new MyModel { Id = "2", MyData = "Second Item"},
        };

        foreach (MyModel model in myModels)
        {
            context.Set<MyModel>().Add(model);
        }

        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

The *first* time you run this you may have to use the ClearDatabaseSchemaAlways as baseclass to force the model to get updated with the two entities:

```
public class MyInitializer : ClearDatabaseSchemaAlways<todoitemContext>
```

But from then on you can just use the ClearDatabaseSchemaAIfModelChanges again.

Hope this helps!

Henrik

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But i actually dont see a difference between mine code and yours. I had also **added** a `public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels` and filled it like `context.Set<MyModel>().Add(new MyModel{MyData= "test"});` - a simplified version of yours sample. Can you, please, highlight a differences one more time: i'm afraid, i didnt get them?

Comment: Updated a question. That exception in mobile app says that it cant see a table, but table exists...