# Create new SQL table for Azure Mobile Apps/Services w/ .NET backend

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have found several different ways to do what I am trying to do but I have absolutely no clue why is it that my ways are failing one after the other. Here is my setup:

- I have a Azure Mobile App/Service (I understand Mobile Services is phasing out, my setup is with Mobile Apps btw) that I want to deploy. Of course the default `TodoItem` that is given to me is useless, so I want to add my own item, which I call `Digest`.
- I make a model for the item that I am trying to add, which looks like this:

  ```
  public class Digests : EntityData
  {
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string ImageURI { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Of course, I also made a controller using the tools in Visual Studio 2015, so nothing new there.

Now we go to the fun part. How in the world is it that I can create a table that has the data in my `Digest` item? Let me explain to you what I have done so far:

1. I went into the `My_App_Context.cs` and added `public DbSet<Digests> DigestItems { get; set; }` right below the default `public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }` that was already there in the first place. Supposedly this should create a table in my Azure SQL database associated with my Mobile Service/App.
2. I went to `Startup.MobileApp.cs` and added `context.Set<Digests>().Add(new Digests { Id = "2016", Title="Test" ,ImageURI = "random_url"});` in the `Initializer` class. This is supposed to populate a row in the table that I created on step one. Please note the class inherits from `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` and I haven't changed that because that worked with the default template (`TodoItem`) that the Azure Team provides.

The bottom line is that after all of this, absolutely nothing happens. I go into the server using SQL Server Management Studio and there is nothing at all, not even a TodoItem table (which should be there because I never, ever modified the template code).

What makes me even more confused is that if I set up a whole other Mobile App/Service with a whole other database and I just make the template app and back-end provided run as-is it works to perfection. Tables, insertion, deletion and all other things get created and populated with no problem, but when I add literally 5 lines of code not only my code does not do anything, but also seems to block in some way the `TodoItem` code already given to me.

All I want to do I to get the table to get created so that I can have a client download its contents using the Azure APIs. Please any help is greatly appreciated.

**Here is all the new code I add:**

1. A new `DataObject` called `Digests`:

   ```
   public class Digests : EntityData
   {
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string ImageURI { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Of course, I generate the data object controller.
3. This line of code in `My_App_Context.cs`: `public DbSet<Digests> DigestItems { get; set; }`
4. This line of code on my `Startup.MobileApp.cs` on the `AppInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` class: `context.Set<Digests>().Add(new Digests { Id = "2016", Title="Test", ImageURI = "someUriHere"});`

Comment: Which five lines of code are you adding between it working and not working?

Comment: To messy to add in comments, please see edits in question.

Comment: What I want to do should work by doing only `public DbSet<Digests> DigestItems { get; set; }` in `My_App_Context.cs` if I am not mistaken, but nothing.

Comment: Does it create the default tables todo and Digestitems?  is the issue just the default data you want added?

Comment: Yes. If I just run the default code it creates the TodoItem table with the seed data, but not the table I wanted to add.

Comment: Your digests model doesn't have an ID which it will require for a key.  Does todo class inherit from EntityData?

Comment: Yes, and todo class does not have Id either

Comment: Without the project I am stumped, probably something daft.  Good luck.

Comment: So there is nothing that you see wrong? Argh, thanks. I'll keep trying

Comment: Just tried again, this time only added the model, the controller and `public DbSet<Digests> DigestItems { get; set; }` in `My_App_Context.cs`. Nothing....

Comment: You are updating the same context rather than creating another one, so your context has public DbSet<Digests>....  and ToDo line?

Comment: Yes. There is `public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }` and then 
        `public DbSet<Digests> DigestItems { get; set; }`

Comment: Is that something terrible? What am I missing?

Comment: No, its fine.  So if you remove your seed code, do you get a table created for digests

Comment: Nope. I tried to see if it made an empty table but nothing. It doesn't even make a TodoItems table. Maybe I am not waiting long enough? Should I have to wait more? I have no idea why the TodoItems table isn't getting created.

Comment: This is what I am using as reference, but what worked for him doesn't seem to be working for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016543/extending-base-mobile-azure-sample-net-backend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116895/discussion-between-ananhalz-and-steve-newton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add anything to AppContext.cs, this is already done when you create the table controller.

Comment: The issue you were probably seeing is that Entity Framework does lazy database creation. So, unless you run the Seed method or migrations manually from Visual Studio, the database will not be created or seeded until you do your first request. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724320/forcing-code-first-to-always-initialize-a-non-existent-database for example.